# client request for get http://localhost:3000/test.s

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am creating my website using MEAN stack. on server NodeJs is running which has a route /test and is connected to DB. on the cleint side in Angularjs my client.ejs template include a script like
 
which is used in the controller in the page body.Now if i click on some page which  hit the route /test and Nodejs renders load client.ejs. i can see an error " 500 internal error" for Get request http://localhost:3000/test.js
Why? it is happening like this?

nodejs code:

```
app.post("/test",function(req,res))
{

    /do some stuff with req
    res.status(200);
    res.render("public/hello");
}
```

hello.ejs:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script scr="test.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="my-controller">
   <form ng-submit="dosction()"> 
    <input type=text>
    <input type=submit>
   </form>
  </div>
 </head>
<html>
```

test.js

```
angular.module("my-app",[]).controller("my-controller", function($scope){

dosaction=function()
{

//some stuff

}});
```

Comment: Please add some example code since your question is completely unclear this way.

Comment: It shouldn't be making a request for /test.js since you don't have a script element with a src attribute that points to that URL. (You have a spelling error. Try providing a [**proper** reduced test case](http://sscce.org/) which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you're getting an internal server error, why haven't you told us what the server's error logging says?

Comment: It says it try to look for test.js in the views folder( the folder path set as app.set('views',path.join(__direname,'view')) in nodejs code) but coulld not find. my doubt it that test.js is a script in hello.ejs then why is server looking for this script in views folder? may be becoz of Get request goes to server but then why we are sending this get request for test.js?